# Getting file as rows and columns data matrix

Tags: csv

I have gene.csv file which is about 1.3 GB in size and has got 300 columns and more than a million rows. it looks like following

```
id1      id2    id3    id4         count1      count2
S1001    450    GAF    ARHGAP18    1.56E-05    1483
S1001    450    GAF    ARHGAP12    5E-05       3698
S1001    450    GAF    ARHGAP15    2.75E-06    93
S1001    450    GAF    ARHGAP17    3E-05       1889
S1001    450    GAF    ARHGAP19    4.291E-06   596
S1002    450    GAF    ARHGAP18    5.955E-05   5353
S1002    450    GAF    ARHGAP12    8.578E-08   14
S1002    450    BAF    ARHGAP15    2.91E-05    5381
S1002    450    BAF    ARHGAP17    1.78E-06    105
S1002    450    BAF    ARHGAP19    3.62E-05    5764
S1003    450    BAF    ARHGAP18    5.2697E-06  330
S1003    450    BAF    ARHGAP12    5.955E-05   2263
S1003    450    BAF    ARHGAP15    8.578E-08   3147
S1003    450    CAF    ARHGAP17    2.91E-05    50
S1003    450    CAF    ARHGAP19    5.955E-05   1595
S1004    450    CAF    ARHGAP18    8.578E-08   970
S1004    450    CAF    ARHGAP12    2.91E-05    816
S1004    450    CAF    ARHGAP15    5.955E-05   4981
S1004    450    CAF    ARHGAP17    8.578E-08   816
S1004    450    CAF    ARHGAP19    2.91E-05    4981
```

I want only id1, id4 and count2 data fetched in the following format (as a matrix)

```
id4        S1001   S1002 S1003  S1004
ARHGAP18    1483   5353  330    970
ARHGAP12    3698   14    2263   816
ARHGAP15    93     5381  3147   4981
ARHGAP17    1889   105   50     816
ARHGAP19    596    5764  1595   4981
```

Please note i need to be repeated only once and as a column name in a new file (Since id1 is repeated in each row for each gene). How can i get this in from simple bash command (matrix of gene names(rows) and sample ids (columns).

Comment: do you have python `pandas` installed?

Comment: Hi Roman, I am not a programmer, I am a biologist and I am not very well with python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with Miller, using [reshape](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference-verbs.html#reshape)

```
mlr --tsv cut -o -f id4,id1,count2 then reshape -s id1,count2 input.tsv
```

you will have

```
id4     S1001   S1002   S1003   S1004
ARHGAP18        1483    5353    330     970
ARHGAP12        3698    14      2263    816
ARHGAP15        93      5381    3147    4981
ARHGAP17        1889    105     50      816
ARHGAP19        596     5764    1595    4981
```

As input and output I have set a TSV file. Is you text file tab separated?

Some comment:

- `--tsv` is to set input & output format;
- `cut` to extract only id4,id1 and count2;
- `reshape` to modify the structure.

Comment: it did not output as desired, in fact after reshape it showed only 3 columns. my command was mlr reshape -s icgc_specimen_id,raw_read_count miller_1.tsv

Comment: @David I think you are using another input file. Please could you share some rows here?

Comment: I have made an example file with only min rows, but the original file is of 2.7 GBs.Please have a look at the following link, here I need only [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1joMO2D1RuppJBbepeEu3-lLA7LQZJeJR/view?usp=sharing] i need icgc_specimen_id as colmns, gene_id as row and raw_read_count column. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @David there is no link

Comment: hi @dave the command for this new file is `mlr --tsv cut -o -f icgc_specimen_id,gene_id,raw_read_count then reshape -s gene_id,raw_read_count then unsparsify --fill-with "" exp_seq_example.csv  >out.tsv`. Here the [output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EAdLiq92DJrWKmKCgfvQc68eoyVsueNy_uudlevJIB8/edit#gid=474297523)

Comment: Thanks, can i get icgc_specimen_id as Column id instead of gene id?

Comment: Hi @David could you insert a link of an example of output you want?
Because in my output icgc_specimen_id is a column

Comment: Hi @David with `mlr --tsv cut -o -f gene_id,icgc_specimen_id,raw_read_count then reshape -s icgc_specimen_id,raw_read_count then unsparsify --fill-with "" exp_seq_example.csv >tmp.tsv` you have [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EAdLiq92DJrWKmKCgfvQc68eoyVsueNy_uudlevJIB8/edit#gid=2104587764). Is it right?

Comment: Awesome! It worked! Thanks a lot for your kind help... You made my day!

Comment: @David how long is the processing of this big file?

Comment: First, it crashed my system, Later I had split the file into 4 parts and the file was processed in half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a *cross-tabulation* (or pivot table). You can achieve it using [GNU Datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)

```
datamash --header-in --whitespace crosstab id4,id1 unique count2 < file
    S1001   S1002   S1003   S1004
ARHGAP12    3698    14  2263    816
ARHGAP15    93  5381    3147    4981
ARHGAP17    1889    105 50  816
ARHGAP18    1483    5353    330 970
ARHGAP19    596 5764    1595    4981
```

(you can skip the `--whitespace` if your data are tab delimited).

However there may be dedicated bioinformatics tools that are better suited to the task.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code works like a charm. Thanks a ton!